# How to use the output of an Indirect Kalman Filter (= error state Kalman filter)

Tags: kalman-filter

I would like to measure true orientation with an IMU sensor by using an indirect Kalman filter (IKF).

I can calculate the error of angle and error of the bias of the gyro from the indirect Kalman filter as in the attached image.

However, I can not remove the bias of gyro despite using error of bias calculated from IKF like in the attached image.

I would like to know how to use the IKF's output.

[image]

Comment: I remember Phil Labs (Phil Salmony) made a 4 movie youtube series about this. Very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2012/09/a-practical-approach-to-kalman-filter-and-how-to-implement-it/) they use a Kalman filter to estimate the bias of the rate gyro and then subtract it from the true rate but they are running the states with only rate gyro info:

so their rate states are:

$$ x_k =\begin{bmatrix} \theta_k \\ \dot{\theta_k}  \end{bmatrix} $$

then they subtract the bias from the new rate:

```
rate = newRate - bias;
angle += dt * rate;
```

In this other [article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Guide-to-gyro-and-accelerometer-with-Arduino-inclu/) when they combine the two they use a fraction of each the accelerometer and rate gyro.

```
 angle = 0.98 *(angle+gyro*dt) + 0.02*acc
```

Hope this helps.

One thing I'd like to add is this works for a 6DOF sensor, but its better to have add a magnetometer so then you have a solid (well as long as you can trust magnetic north) sensor updating your rates.